# Write variable in text format in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have problem in writting variable as key in array

```js
    setOrderedItems((cartItem) => ({...cartItem, item.id: item.name}));
```

I've tried `{item.id}` and `${item.id}`, but nothing works.

```js
    const [orderedItems, setOrderedItems] = useState([]);
    const handleOnChange = (item, eventStatus) => {
    if(eventStatus){
      setOrderedItems((cartItem) => ({...cartItem, [item.id]: item.name}));
    }
    }
```

The item is a single item that has a structure.

```js
    /* first item */ {id: 1, name: 'test1'} 
    /* second item */ {id: 1, name: 'test2'} 
    /* third item */ {id: 2, name: 'test3}
```

What I want to achive is `{1: ['test1', 'test2'], 2: 'test3'}`

Comment: Please provide more code to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `item.id` holds the `key` to be used for the `item.name` value in the object you're creating, use square brackets:

```js
setOrderedItems((cartItem) => ({ ...cartItem, [item.id]: item.name }))
```

---

Update: so apparently you want to accumulate multiple string values under the same key. In more detail, from these items:

```js
[
  { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
  { id: 1, name: 'test2' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test3' }
]
```

you want to obtain

```js
{
  1: ['test1', 'test2'],
  2: ['test3']
}
```

This should do it:

```
const [orderedItems, setOrderedItems] = React.useState({})

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1" },
  { id: 1, name: "test2" },
  { id: 2, name: "test3" }
]
const addItem = React.useCallback(({ id, name }) => {
  setOrderedItems({
    ...orderedItems,
    [id]: [...(orderedItems[id] || []), name]
  })
}, [])
data.forEach(addItem)
console.log(orderedItems)
/* 
 {
   1: ['test1', 'test2'],
   2: ['test3']
 }
*/
```

Comment: and how can I do that next item name will be added to item.id. Right now it works but when I add next item the last item is overwritten.

Comment: How am I supposed to know what you're trying to achieve? Don't you think you should show the data structure you currently have and the one you're trying to obtain?

Comment: I want efekt like this {1: 'test1', 'test2', 2: 'test3'} And when I change code I've got only {1: 'test1', 2: 'test3'}

Comment: How can I avoid overwritten the value in key?

Comment: `{1: 'test1', 'test2', 2: 'test3'}` is not a valid object. I strongly suggest you show exactly the data you have and exactly the data you try to obtain. Make sure both are valid. Without that information, I won't be able to help.

Comment: const [orderedItems, setOrderedItems] = useState([]);
const handleOnChange = (item, eventStatus) => {
    if(eventStatus){
      setOrderedItems((cartItem) => ({...cartItem, [item.id]: item.name}));
}
}
The item is single item which has structe {id: 1, name: 'test1'} second item {id: 1, name: 'test2'} third item {id: 2, name: 'test3}
What I want to achive is {1: {'test1', 'test2'}, 2: 'test3'}

Comment: The result you're trying to achieve is invalid: In more detail `{'test1', 'test2'}` is invalid. You probably want arrays: `{ 1: ['test1', 'test2']`, 2: ['test3']}`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, You are right I want in that structure, sorry for my miss click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you illegally added the `id` attribute to the key.

```js
setOrderedItems((cartItem) => ({...cartItem, item:[{ id: item.name}]}));
```

Comment: It didn't help. I want to read what is in item.id and assign value item.name. For example 1: {asd, blabla}

Comment: Write now  I have item: Array(1)
0: {id: asd}

Comment: @zxc Please provide more code to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i give more details